# Easy to implement slider-gallery

Tags: php, html, css

I'm looking for some easy to implement gallery for my site.

The best option for me would be gallery that has those futures. 
Number of stars shows how important is that for me.

- Load all images from directory ****
- Resize images to fit to gallery area (landscape, portrait) ***
- Show images title *
- easy to implement **
- Works on all browsers ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[galleria!](http://galleria.aino.se/)** *(honest)* It took me **3 hours** to set up a **complete slideshow** with Picasa **from scratch**. Galleria is a JavaScript image gallery framework built on top of the **jQuery library**. The aim is to simplify the process of creating professional image galleries for the web and mobile devices. It supports **all of your requirements**.

**[docs here](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/)**

Comment: Can you tell me how to change that default black background?

Comment: just edit the Stylesheet/CSS that comes with the code, I believe it is in the galleria-container class.(on top)

Comment: @ Caspar Kleijne - Strange. I changes all black colors to white and bg is still black.

Comment: Yes, I used that classic.min.js